# Is there a word for the instant after you are slapped and are deciding how to react?

Tags: single-word-requests

Or just any kind of semi-unexpected personal injury. Maybe someone destroys the painting you spent months on.

So after the inciting incident, there's a split second where you're trying to figure out what to do. You feel a hot rush as your primal instinct is to lash out in anger, but your intellect is trying to tell you that maybe there's a better way.

Is there a word for that moment/decision?

Comment: I'd call it the _flush_ of immediate pain and anger—especially appropriate if you are slapped in the face.

Comment: Only the one in that state should know.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I think the most appropriate word would be "Stunned".

*Astonish or shock (someone) so that they are temporarily unable to react.*

Answer (score 3):

I think the phrase **taken aback** can be used this situation.

[TheFreeDictionary](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/taken+aback) defines this phrase as:

> confused or surprised by something unexpected

It offers the following examples:

> When Mary told me the news, I was taken aback for a moment. When I told my parents I was married, they were completely taken aback. Company executives have been taken aback by the criticism. I asked him directly if he was looking for someone with my skills, and I think he was kind of taken aback.

There are also [examples](https://www.google.com/webhp?hl=en#hl=en&q=%22taken%20aback%20*%20slap%22) of this phrase on Google used to describe people who were slapped.

Comment: Yes, "taken aback" is a rather old idiom, but well-recognized, and is the first that came to mind when I saw the question.  Perhaps not an ideal fit for a slap, though -- I'd maybe say "stunned".

Answer (score 2):

"Nonplussed"

It means: Surprised and confused so much so that one is unsure how to react.

Comment: Unfortunately, the American variant of the language has changed the meaning of this word to something closer to "nonchalant". But if you're not in the USA you'll be okay. :)

Comment: Agreed. The North American usage is different.

Answer (score 1):

A **pause** is a temporary inaction especially as caused by an uncertainty.  (Merriam-Webster)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the expression ***shocked silence***.

Examples:

> This time SAMIR is slapped on the face. After the slap SAMIR stands in **shocked silence** as he is about to burst into tears.
>
> <sub>*Talk to Me: Monologue Plays* edited by Eric Lane, Nina Shengold</sub>
>
> ---
>
> I slapped him hard with the back of my hand. 'Silence fool' I said, he stood there in **shocked silence** as I continued.
>
> <sub>*Fear the Reaper: Special Edition* By Fritz O'Skennick</sub>
>
> ---
>
> She ripped the cuts so that his knees and chest were exposed. Ben watched in **shocked silence** as she destroyed his clothes.
>
> <sub>*Yours Unfaithfully*  By Deer, Geraldine C. Deer</sub>
>
> ---
>
> An earthquake came along one day and the magnificent lighthouse was shaken to bits – completely destroyed!' There was a **shocked silence**.
>
> <sub>*Famous Five 19: Five Go To Demon's Rocks* By Enid Blyton</sub>

Answer (score 0):

*[Reaction time](http://www.merriam-webster.com/medical/reaction%20time)* (*latent time/ latency*)

> *noun*
>   Medical Definition of REACTION TIME
>   :  the time elapsing between the beginning of the application of a stimulus and the beginning of an organism's reaction to it

It's actually a very broad term. When you see an obstacle in the way and apply brakes, your **reaction time** varies according to various factors.